# How to set up multiple PATHs in the user bash_profile in OSX 10.8?

Tags: macos, bash, python

I am looking to set up my laptop for both Python development and Phonegap Android development in OSX 10.8 using Eclipse. I installed the lastest version of Python (3.3) which added the code:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.3
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

to my `.bash_profile`. In process of setting up Phonegap you need to set up the PATH for the Android Development tools with the following line:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools
```

Is it possible to set up both `PATH`s in the `.bash_profile` so that Python and Android development can take place simultaneously? Or would I need to switch between the PATHs depending on what type of development I would like to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly possible to have both statements coexist happily in `.bash_profile`. This file is evaluated sequentially from top to bottom, and the same environment variable (`$PATH` in this case) can be modified multiple times. If you wish, you can edit both into a single command:

`export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Development/android-sdk-macosx/tools"`

to do both modifications at the same time, but this is no different from your current setup. Happy Pythoning!

Comment: Thanks! I've got both the Python and Android commands working.